# Ensuring that subdirectories won't be affected by a loop (or by find)

Tags: bash, find, apache-httpd, for

Please review these codes that are aimed to do basically the same task (finding the main `.htaccess` of the site and changing it):

```
for dir in "$HOME"/public_html/*.{com,co.il}/; do 
  if pushd "$dir"; then 
    chmod 644 .htaccess 
    popd 
  fi 
done 2>/dev/null
```

and:

```
find "$HOME"/public_html/*.{com,co.il} -name ".htaccess" -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Should these also affect `.htaccess` files in subdirectories of each directory under `public_html`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, the first loop only considers files in the immediate directory structure you've listed (with the wildcards filled in, of course). The `find` command that you've listed does not restrict itself to any level of directory structure, and would run `chmod` on any *and all* files named .htaccess in the directory tree.

To restrict the `find` command to only the directory structure it starts in (noting that you've given it, via globs, multiple starting directories), add the `-maxdepth 1` predicate:

```
find "$HOME"/public_html/*.{com,co.il} -maxdepth 1 -name ".htaccess" -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Answer (score 4):

Your first code snippet:

```
for dir in "$HOME"/public_html/*.{com,co.il}/; do 
  if pushd "$dir"; then 
    chmod 644 .htaccess 
    popd 
  fi 
done 2>/dev/null
```

This could be rewritten without changing into and out of directories, as

```
for dir in "$HOME"/public_html/*.{com,co.il}/; do 
    chmod 644 "$dir/.htaccess" 
done 2>/dev/null
```

and even be shortened (or at least modified) from that to

```
for pathname in "$HOME"/public_html/*.{com,co.il}/.htaccess; do 
    chmod 644 "$pathname" 
done 2>/dev/null
```

which, if there are not too many of those files, could be done with

```
chmod 644 "$HOME"/public_html/*.{com,co.il}/.htaccess 2>/dev/null
```

This only looks at the `.htaccess` files in subdirectories of `public_html`, and not further down into the directory structure.

Note that the last two variations will not try to `chmod` missing files.  The original loop and my first variant of it *assumes* that there are `.htaccess` files to `chmod` in the given directories, while the last two variants just loops over the `.htaccess` files that are actually present.  The earlier loops gives you an opportunity to test whether a directory contains such a file (which you don't do), whereas the later commands assumes that the `.htaccess` files that are there are the only ones that we need to concern ourselves with.

Your second code snippet:

```
find "$HOME"/public_html/*.{com,co.il} -name ".htaccess" -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

This on the other hand looks for `.htaccess` files anywhere in or below the directories defined by `"$HOME"/public_html/*.{com,co.il}`. You could remedy that by adding `-maxdepth 1` before `-name`.  This would stop `find` from recursing down into subdirectories of the given directories and force it to stop at the top level.

Adding `-maxdepth 1` to `find` makes it work pretty much the same way as my last actual loop above.

Neither of the two commands tries to verify that the found `.htaccess` files are actually regular files and not directories etc.  In your loop, you could do that with a `-f` test, and in the `find` command, you could do that by saying `-type f` before the `-exec`.